# Cocos Creator SecureWebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, cocoscreator

I am trying to create an app with Cocos Creator, the scripts are written in JavaScript.
My app requires a WebSocketSecure (wss) connection.

For some reason, this is working fine in the simulator in an mac and the app itself works fine on an iPhone, but for some reason the wss connection cannot be opened on a windows pc or an android phone.

Does anyone know what could be the solution for this?

This is the js code used in the example:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
ws.onopen = (event) => {
    console.log("connected");
};
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log("message received");
};
ws.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log("error");
};
ws.onclosed = (event) => {
    console.log("closed");
};
```

The event parameters in onerror and onclosed only provide the type (which is 'error' or 'closed') and the used url.

Best regards

Comment: It's hard to tell without a further description. Please include error logs, configuration options (if relevant), and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: I have put the used code in the post.
For some reason I am not getting actual error logs.
I am new to StackOverflow, is there an option to upload .zip files?

Comment: No, but if the minimal amount of code required to ***reproduce the issue*** is too large, a popular solution is to build a minimal github repository.

Comment: This is basically the minimal amount of code. It is in the onLoad() method in a component attached to a setup node.
Anyways, here you can find the whole project.
https://github.com/Orlan2806/WebSocketTest